# Actionlogging with Node

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql, transaction-log

I am quite sure that I am not the first person on the planet trying to implement the following, but I am sure that I am not able to find a good guide how to do it.

Our node backend is setup quite like a MVC to say so.

View = Express Server offering our api

Controller = Library, a set of controller functions to manage our data

Model = Our mysql database, it's Javascript DAO respectively (since our usecase is quite unique we need to write own DAO's and can not go let's say for `js-data`.

The challenge we face now, is:

- As a developer, I want to keep our library clean from overhead for developers.
- On the other side, as a database administrator I clearly want to know who did what modification and so on

Until now I tried to keep the 'user' object out of the library, since I do not want all controller functions to look like

`function ctrl(param1, param2, param..., user)`

Going for this would mean, we have to pass around User objects all the time, which would make it a pain to code inside the libraries.

On the other hand, I can not find any other approach in node/express to somehow get knowledge about the user without passing it (since we do not really have sessions, at least not yet in our code).

TL:DR; I do want to action log all database modifications, but do not want to pass around a User object all the time.

Is there any known approach for that challenge which does scale and is 'best practice'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is last place where that user object is available in your code?

Comment: In the "API", from there I delegate to the library (already without user identification). In the express middleware functions.

Comment: If you're delegating in asynchronous way then you can simply log it inside callback...

Comment: Id like to bind it as close as possible. Like:
Update table set x.
User p updated table set y to x.